# JSoup crawling how to crawl from same tag but two items

Tags: java, jsoup

[image: For explaining]

I need to crawl all three items in span tag. i have some code but i need a few hints. This is my code until now.

```
News n = new News();
n.setHeadline(news.getElementsByTag("h2").first().text());
n.setTypeOfSport(news.getElementsByTag("span").first().text());

n.setDate(news.getElementsByTag("span").);

n.setTime(news.getElementsByTag("span").);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to pick all `span` elements from `<div class="info">` and access them based on their position (index).

Assuming that your `news` variable is of type `Document` or `Element`(s) you should have access to `select(CSSquery)` method. If it also at some level holds this `<div class="info">` your code can look like:

```
Elements spans = news.select("div.info span");

//now you can get and handle text from all spans via
spans.get(0).text();
spans.get(1).text();
spans.get(2).text();
```

For more info about selecting elements using CSS see https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: `Elements` is iterable so you can use loop:
 ```for(Element span : spans){ ... }```

Comment: @KrystianG True, but loops make sense if we are repeating same steps. Based on what I understand from question this is not the case, since text from each span should be used as argument for different method (`n.setTypeOfSport(..)`, `n.setDate(..)`, `n.setTime(..)`)

Comment: You are right. It was just a general tip for the author of this question. Might be useful sooner or later taking into account he didn't know he could use get(int).